# Css and Html website

Tags: html, css

I have a few problems here that i would really appreciate some help with only using css and html

1. The footer is hidden behind text and not on the bottom
2. There is an unnecessary scroll bar that goes horizontally
3. The word sunset is hidden behind the transparent box I would like it  above

thanks guys

```css
body, h1, h2, h3, section{
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
 border: 0;}

body{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
 font-size:100%;
 background: url(http://www.desktopwallpaperhd.net/wallpapers/15/9/landscape-sea-sunset-clouds-afternoon-search-wallpaper-beach-coast-trees-159369.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;}

.page{
 position:relative;}

.wrap{ max-width: 1200px;  margin: 0 auto; }
section::after{
 content:''; display:block; clear: both;}

section{
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.45);}

.wrap h1{
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 5px;
 font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
 text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(252,143,47,1.00);}

article{
 color:white;}

.left{
 float: left;}

.right{
 float: right;}

nav a{ 
 color: #232323;
 font-weight:400;
 font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
 text-align:center;}

nav a:hover{
 color: grey;}

nav{
 z-index:1;}

footer a {
 color: rgba(255,153,0,1);
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;}

footer{
 font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif; 
 bottom: 0px;}

.wrap{
 position: relative; 
 top: 500px;}

section{
 width: 100%;
 margin-top:3em;}
  
article{
 width: 45%;
 padding: 1.2%;
 margin: 0 .7em;}

nav{
 position: absolute; top: 0px; 
 width: 100%; height:40px;
 background-color:white; 
 padding:10px;}

nav a{
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 padding: .5em 1em .3em 0;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-decoration:none;}  

footer{
 width: 100%; height:50px;
 font-size: .85em;
 color: #232323;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: white;}

nav a.X{
 float:left;}
```

```html
</head>
 <nav>
    <a class="X"> SHEN </a>
    <a href="http">Contact us</a>
    <a href="http">Cost of Attendance</a>
    <a href="http">Distinguished Alumni</a>
    <a href="http">National recognition</a></nav>
 
<body>
<header>

</header>   

<div class="page">
<div class="wrap">
<h1>
SUNSET
</h1>
<section>

      <article class="left">
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec augue sed, consequat tortor libero libero condimentum molestie, commodo id metus dignissim aenean ante ligula, nam proin rhoncus cras, amet sed vestibulum. Id id orci dui mauris, commodo dolor sapien, orci etiam mauris, vivamus nulla lorem nisl nulla quam maecenas, donec fames amet. Amet cras hymenaeos vehicula gravida erat, id sapien odio pariatur orci vivamus. Etiam donec ornare mi egestas condimentum mattis, sed lacinia pellentesque ut, ac adipiscing dui in sodales a, pede id imperdiet amet feugiat suscipit. Cras velit est, ipsum integer, elit donec. </p>
<p>Nullam turpis et eget cras risus placeat. Velit aenean. Porttitor lectus vel enim amet aptent et, mollis non volutpat nullam eros aliquam.</p>
  
  <p>Ac interdum vel nonummy, ultricies vitae nunc, faucibus tempus, sodales nibh penatibus porta elementum mi, eu eu. Vitae ornare tortor, suscipit integer eros cras vestibulum, orci condimentum integer lacus. eros cras vestibulum.</p></article>
        <article class="right">
<p>Nullam turpis et eget cras risus placeat. Velit aenean. Porttitor lectus vel enim amet aptent et, mollis non volutpat nullam eros aliquam.</p>
  
  <p>Ac interdum vel nonummy, ultricies vitae nunc, faucibus tempus, sodales nibh penatibus porta elementum mi, eu eu. Vitae ornare tortor, suscipit integer eros cras vestibulum, orci condimentum integer lacus. Sed tellus placerat neque dolor vel risus, nulla primis elit orci sem condimentum nunc, sociis eget, ac ea convallis vestibulum. Vitae magna dui, molestie sed quis wisi convallis augue consequat, nunc ac arcu orci in diam venenatis, integer vitae vel nec, amet vestibulum ligula suspendisse dui eleifend. Diam ut nisl vel odio cras torquent, a nec dictum vehicula vitae, neque venenatis luctus metus ligula natoque, nec sed pede ligula sit cupiditate elementum, in vestibulum mauris amet tortor nascetur. Egestas qui tincidunt est, nibh sed vitae penatibus, orci pellentesque sem fames morbi tortor, tristique rhoncus nascetur aenean velit mi. Id sed elit suspendisse.</p></article>
  </section>
  
 </div>
 <footer>&copy; <a href="#">Me</a>, Kalamazoo, MI 49008 | 
      <!-- #BeginDate format:Am1 -->April 20, 2016<!-- #EndDate -->
</footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at sticky footer: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: This would be a lot easier to fix if you combined the CSS for each part, rather than having two `footer` pieces and two `section` pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Best way: Try to use a framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), where you have to just put the divs in the right class, css is already done for you.

Alternative:

You may fix the footer to a sticky footer. But I see a lot of other problems in your code like divs with-in divs for no reason, footer and header tags etc.
Try to follow a schema through out, example :

HTML

```
<div class="page-wrap">

  Content!

</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

This is just an example from [Sticky footer](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
body, h1, h2, h3, section{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;}

body{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:100%;
background: url(http://www.desktopwallpaperhd.net/wallpapers/15/9/landscape-sea-sunset-clouds-afternoon-search-wallpaper-beach-coast-trees-159369.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;}

.page{
    position:relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.wrap{  max-width: 1100px;  margin: 0 auto;}
section::after{
content:''; display:block; clear: both;}

section{
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.45);}

.wrap h1{
position: absolute; top: 0; right: 5px;
font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    /*
    changes that have been made
    i have added this property
   color:white;
   by the way the word "sunset" is on the above of the transparent box
    */
    color:white;
text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(252,143,47,1.00);
}

article{
color:white;}

.left{
float: left;}

.right{
float: right;}

nav a{
color: #232323;
font-weight:400;
font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
text-align:center;}

nav a:hover{
color: grey;}

nav{
z-index:1;}

footer{
    width: 100%; height:30px;
    font-size: .85em;
    color: #232323;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
    /*
   changes that have been made
   i have added this property
    position:fixed;
   */
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}

footer a {
    color: rgba(255,153,0,1);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;}

.wrap{
position: relative;
top: 500px;}

section{
width: 100%;
margin-top:3em;}

article{
width: 45%;
padding: 1.2%;
margin: 0 .7em;}

nav{
position: absolute; top: 0px;
    /*
    changes that have been made
    width:100% change to 1200px
    */
width: 1200px; height:40px;
background-color:white;
padding:10px;}

nav a{
display: inline-block;
float: right;
padding: .5em 1em .3em 0;
font-size: 1.1em;
text-decoration:none;}



nav a.X{
float:left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>

</header>
<nav>
    <a class="X"> SHEN </a>
    <a href="http">Contact us</a>
    <a href="http">Cost of Attendance</a>
    <a href="http">Distinguished Alumni</a>
    <a href="http">National recognition</a></nav>
<div class="page">
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>
            SUNSET
        </h1>

        <section>

            <article class="left">
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec augue sed, consequat tortor libero libero condimentum molestie, commodo id metus dignissim aenean ante ligula, nam proin rhoncus cras, amet sed vestibulum. Id id orci dui mauris, commodo dolor sapien, orci etiam mauris, vivamus nulla lorem nisl nulla quam maecenas, donec fames amet. Amet cras hymenaeos vehicula gravida erat, id sapien odio pariatur orci vivamus. Etiam donec ornare mi egestas condimentum mattis, sed lacinia pellentesque ut, ac adipiscing dui in sodales a, pede id imperdiet amet feugiat suscipit. Cras velit est, ipsum integer, elit donec. </p>
                <p>Nullam turpis et eget cras risus placeat. Velit aenean. Porttitor lectus vel enim amet aptent et, mollis non volutpat nullam eros aliquam.</p>

                <p>Ac interdum vel nonummy, ultricies vitae nunc, faucibus tempus, sodales nibh penatibus porta elementum mi, eu eu. Vitae ornare tortor, suscipit integer eros cras vestibulum, orci condimentum integer lacus. eros cras vestibulum.</p></article>
            <article class="right">
                <p>Nullam turpis et eget cras risus placeat. Velit aenean. Porttitor lectus vel enim amet aptent et, mollis non volutpat nullam eros aliquam.</p>

                <p>Ac interdum vel nonummy, ultricies vitae nunc, faucibus tempus, sodales nibh penatibus porta elementum mi, eu eu. Vitae ornare tortor, suscipit integer eros cras vestibulum, orci condimentum integer lacus. Sed tellus placerat neque dolor vel risus, nulla primis elit orci sem condimentum nunc, sociis eget, ac ea convallis vestibulum. Vitae magna dui, molestie sed quis wisi convallis augue consequat, nunc ac arcu orci in diam venenatis, integer vitae vel nec, amet vestibulum ligula suspendisse dui eleifend. Diam ut nisl vel odio cras torquent, a nec dictum vehicula vitae, neque venenatis luctus metus ligula natoque, nec sed pede ligula sit cupiditate elementum, in vestibulum mauris amet tortor nascetur. Egestas qui tincidunt est, nibh sed vitae penatibus, orci pellentesque sem fames morbi tortor, tristique rhoncus nascetur aenean velit mi. Id sed elit suspendisse.</p></article>
        </section>

    </div>
    <footer>&copy; <a href="#">Me</a>, Kalamazoo, MI 49008 |
        <!-- #BeginDate format:Am1 -->April 20, 2016<!-- #EndDate -->
    </footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```